# minimizing and maximizing function with constraint

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying for my calc II exam, and I recently discovered how one can solve max/min problems with constrains using AM-GM inequalities instead of lagrange multipliers. Seeing as this is way more elegant, I'd like to learn more about it.

Could someone help me find the maximum and minimum value of $3+2xy$ subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$. I've already solved it using lagrange multipliers, but I'd like to see how it can be solved using AM-GM aswell.

*(I've only looked at the very basics of AM-GM so far, but I couldn't find much online about how to utilize the inequalities when you have a constraint. Is this worth learning before my exam?)*

Thank you!

Comment: Are $x,y$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: Well no, the task is taken from a previous exam, lagrange was used in the solution but I thought you can use AM-GM. The question was simply to find the maximum and minimum value $3+2xy$ on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, polar coordinates.

$x=r \cos t$, $y=r\sin t$, $0\le t \lt 2π.$

Note: $r =1.$

$F(r,t):= 3+2\sin t \cos t =$

$3+ \sin 2t.$

Minimum, maximum?

Comment: Not quite AM-GM, but this one was quite elegant as well! Thank you for the alternative solution (without using lagrange)

Comment: novo.Welcome.Fairly simple in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

From $$x^2+y^2=1$$ we get
$$(x+y)^2=1+2xy\geq 0$$
For the Maximum prove that $$3+2xy\le 4$$

Comment: I tried setting $\frac{1+2xy}{2} \geq \sqrt{2xy}$ does $\sqrt{2xy}$ simplify to 1?

Comment: This is only correct, when $x,y$ are assumed to be positive!

Comment: Ok, so if the task does not specifiy that $x, y \geq 0$ than I should stick to lagrange multipliers? If we do assume $x, y \geq 0$ can we also find the minimum?

Comment: Yes, then you will get $$3+2xy\geq 1$$

Comment: and since $$x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$$ we get $$3+2xy\le 4$$

Comment: The minimum is supposed to be 2 ?

Comment: No the Minimum is  $2$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+and+minimize+3%2B2xy+on+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1 ?

Comment: Sorry this was my mistake!

Comment: I'm still not about my calculations. We know that $(x+y)^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2$ 
So $1+2xy \geq 0$

and thus $2xy \geq -1 $

How does this work out with 

$1+2xy \geq 2\sqrt{2xy}$

How do you know $x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy$ shouldn't it be

$x^2+y^2 \geq -2xy$ ?